# “No overload matches this call” error when setting up ContextApi & useReducer using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I have problem with setting up the reducer with context API. The error in console point to the reducer file. I have no idea what is going on, since the initial state have the same properties like type `NewsStateContextType`  of reducer state.

```sh
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 5, '(reducer: ReducerWithoutAction<any>, initializerArg: any, initializer?: undefined): [any, DispatchWithoutAction]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: NewsEntryResponse, action: Action) => NewsEntryResponse | { state: NewsEntryResponse; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerWithoutAction<any>'.
  Overload 2 of 5, '(reducer: (state: NewsEntryResponse, action: Action) => NewsEntryResponse | { state: NewsEntryResponse; }, initialState: never, initializer?: undefined): [...]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ count: number; previous: string; next: string; results: never[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Reducer looks like this

```js
export const newsReducer = (state: NewsStateContextType, action: Action) => {
  //console.log('reducer state', state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_NEWS:
      return action.payload;
    case ADD_NEWS:
      return { ...state, results: [...state.results, action.payload] };
    default:
      return { state };
  }
};
```

Types

```js
interface NewsEntryResponse {
  count: number;
  previous: string | null;
  next: string | null;
  results: Array<NewsEntryResult>;
}
export type NewsStateContextType = NewsEntryResponse;

export type Action = AddNewsAction | SetNewsAction;
export type AddNewsAction = { type: typeof ADD_NEWS; payload: NewsEntryResult };
export type SetNewsAction = { type: typeof SET_NEWS; payload: NewsEntryResponse };
```

Controller

```js
export const NewsController = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const INITIAL_STATE = { count: 0, previous: '', next: '', results: [] };
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(newsReducer, INITIAL_STATE);
  //console.log('News Controller state', state);

  return (
    <NewsStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <NewsDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>{children}</NewsDispatchContext.Provider>
    </NewsStateContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the problem was returning the default action in `newsReducer` it should return simply the state object.

```js
export const newsReducer = (state: NewsStateContextType, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_NEWS:
      return action.payload;
    case ADD_NEWS:
      return { ...state, results: [...state.results, action.payload] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```